# Partitioned parquet file takes more space and more time to query

Tags: parquet

Theoretically a Parquet file is expected to take less space than CSV and should provide results quicker. My experiment shows the opposite.
https://github.com/yashgt/Samples/blob/master/Parquet.ipynb

I am converting the CSV file at
to a Parquet file partitioned on the "city" field.

The activity takes 7m

The size of the Parquet folder is 48MB, while CSV is 2.5MB.

Querying the Parquet with a filtering criteria on "city" takes 350ms
while the CSV takes 111ms.

The code is here https://github.com/yashgt/Samples/blob/master/Parquet.ipynb

The executed notebook in PDF form is here https://github.com/yashgt/Samples/raw/master/parquet.pdf

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What's the average number of records per city? If you only have a few records for each then parquet will introduce a big metadata overhead, and the size of files increases.

Answer (score 0):

you should do this test on a much larger dataset to see the expected results. parquet is columnar storage for big data analytics. it has lots of metadata and in your case it might be not efficient compared with the content size itself so you dont have any benefits of the fact that you select only few columns or even all given that this is the dataset size compared to csv.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31256986)